# Implement zoom functionality in layout having images

Tags: android, zooming

I want to implement pinch zoom functionality for a layout which have a background image and on background image it have 4 another image . see the image
[image]

I have `2 idea` to implement my problem

1. Make a parent layout (framelayout) which will have these 4 images as child layout(imageview) and somehow (i dont know how) if i am able to make it pinch zoom. my problem will get solved
2. i can use webview but i dont know how to put these images in webview.

can anyone help me to get it solved.

**Note :** i want pinch zoom functionality only for background image. as if background image will get zoom,  other images will also get zoomed. i dont want independent zoom for images 1 2 3 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. All layouts are already put in to the default `FrameLayout`, so, `Merge` as a root layout is enough.
2. As for zooming the main image, the only problem IMHO, is that these children could sometime catch the event instead of the root layout. So, you need do make them unfocusable and disabled. After that all events will be catched by the parent.